# how to clear auto-complete from my login page

Tags: mysql, authentication

[image]

I'm working on my project that has a login page and i wanted to know how to clear the auto-complete part as it keeps on increasing. Is there a way to clear it

Comment: I don't think there's much the application can do about auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can "autocomplete" attribute of the input field to turn off autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

If you want to turn off auto complete from all input elements of your form then you can use this.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```